# Android Uncaught with no white screen

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, uncaught-exception

I've wanted to avoid the app crash and then I develped the uncaughtException method to call another activity; it works fine. If the app crashes whatever activity, the uncaughtException is called and then my ErrorActivity is shown up.
The problem is when I try to close the app after a crash. When I press the back button, the ErrorActivity is closed, but then a white screen with actionbar shows up and after a few seconds the ErrorActivity is called again. So, there is no way to close the app, except if finalize the app in the taskmanager.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
        {
            handleUncaughtException (thread, e);
        }
    });

}

public void handleUncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable exception)
{

    StringWriter _stackTrace = new StringWriter();
    exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(_stackTrace));

    Intent _intent = new Intent();
    _intent.setAction ("com.mypackage.ERROR_ACTIVITY");
    _intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    _intent.putExtra("error", _stackTrace.toString());
    startActivity(_intent);

    System.exit(0);

}
```

Comment: So you want to close the app onBackPressed? Why don't you just implement @Override onBackPressed in your ErrorActivity and do something like new Finalizer().killApp(true); there?

Comment: And on second thought, try moveTaskToBack(true) instead of System.exit() or new Finalizer().killApp(true).

Comment: I tried it moveTaskToBack(true), but when I try to open the app again, the device stop working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution. It's just add a `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` like following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
        {
            handleUncaughtException (thread, e);
        }
    });

}

public void handleUncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable exception)
{

    StringWriter _stackTrace = new StringWriter();
    exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(_stackTrace));

    Intent _intent = new Intent();
    _intent.setAction("br.com.magazineluiza.mobilevendas.ERROR_ACTIVITY");

    _intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); // Here is the solution

    _intent.putExtra("error", _stackTrace.toString());
    startActivity(_intent);

    System.exit(0); // or System.exit(1) It doesn't matter

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void handleUncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable exception)
{

    StringWriter _stackTrace = new StringWriter();
    exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(_stackTrace));

    Intent _intent = new Intent();
    _intent.setAction ("com.mypackage.ERROR_ACTIVITY");
    _intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    _intent.putExtra("error", _stackTrace.toString());
    startActivity(_intent);

    try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
        });
            Thread.sleep(300);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you execute `system.exit()` when the app crashes, that means it's not a regular `system.exit()` but it's an **exceptional** one, and that means you are better to use `system.exit(1)` rather that `system.exit(0)` and that may fix your problem. this is from [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit%28int%29) "*Termination status. By convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.*".

**UPDATE:**

try to change the intent flag from `NEW_TASK` to `CLEAR_TOP` :

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: I'd already tried it, but didn't work as well. I've also tried system.exit(2), system.exit(10) and so on.